# how to do shift and push operation in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I have an array [1,2,3,4]

I need to continously shift and push one element into the same array

so that the first variable values will be 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,...

and second variable values will be 2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,...

How to do that??

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1411160-exchangeobject

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSMutableArray` like:

1) to get the object at the first position:

```
object = [nameArray firstObject];
[nameArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
```

2) then insert it in last position:

```
[nameArray addObject:object];
```

p.s. remember to always add some sanity checks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1411160-exchangeobject

Comment: @karthikeyan the method you pointing **exchange** objects at given index, OP needs to Pop the first element and Push it in the last position, a FIFO array or a circular buffer. Without reinventing the wheel my answer solves OP problem.

Answer (score -1):

You would need

```
- exchangeObjectAtIndex:withObjectAtIndex:
```

Exchanges the objects in the array at given indices.

See [Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1411160-exchangeobject)

Example

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array setArray:@[@"Eezy",@"Tutorials",@"Website"]];
    [array exchangeObjectAtIndex:0 withObjectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"%@",array); 

NSMutableArray *obj = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",nil];
    [obj exchangeObjectAtIndex:0 withObjectAtIndex:obj.count - 1];

 NSLog(@"%@",obj);
```

Comment: This is completely wrong, taking OP example as input, your code output would be  `4,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,...`